# React - get bounding box of SVG before rendering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg

When an SVG is in the webpage, you can do

`document.getElementById("myPath").getBBox();`

In React, if you try to do this on a component before `render` is executed once, it will of course error because no element with that Id exists yet. What is a good strategy for getting the height and width of an `<g>` or a `<path>` without waiting until after the initial render?

Comment: You can't. The elements haven't been created.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't get what the height and width *will* be once it's rendered?

Comment: Because it's impossible to do in the general case. What if there's a percentage width/height etc. If it's a text element, what's the font-size? Till you put it in the document you don't know these things.

Comment: Got it, thanks @RobertLongson! That's an informative and helpful answer.

Comment: There are different workarounds here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282295/getbbox-of-svg-when-hidden