# How to get notified when my element has been attached to the DOM

Tags: dom, svg, google-maps-api-3

I'm adding a custom control that uses SVG to a Google Map.

After the map has been loaded and my control is shown, I need to grab the BBox from the `svg` element. Since I do not control when my element is attached to the DOM, I'm trying to find an event that will allow me to do the work in a callback.

Here's roughly what I have:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(...);
...
container = document.createElement("div")
svg = createAndDrawSVGElement(...); //this returns an svg element
container.appendChild(svg);
INSERT_THE_RIGHT_EVENT_HERE(function() {
    var bbox = svg.getBBox();
    ... //bbox will be empty if svg isn't attached
}
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(container);
```

My current, ugly workaround is a `setTimeout`. I'd like something more predictable.

Comment: You'll have to show how you actually construct and attach your control, i. e. `createAndDrawSVGElement()` and `addSVGtoContainer()`. The usual pattern is that functions that execute asynchronuously have a mechanism where you can name a callback function that is executed only after the async operation has completed. But to identify that point, we need to see more code.

Comment: @ccprog those functions already exist; I'm not showing them because they are not relevant to the problem. one returns an `svg` element, the other appends it to the `div`. I have fixed my problem in a different way, which I'll post now.

Comment: Duplicate of [GetBBox of SVG when hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282295/getbbox-of-svg-when-hidden)

Comment: I got it wrong because I didn't realise it was the `map.controls[...].push()` that actually attached the element to the DOM. A note of that in the question would probably make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this without an event, by attaching my SVG to a hidden DIV temporarily, so I can get the bbox.

Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45465286/62024

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the API, I would try this (although the doc does not explicitely say whether this is called before or after attaching the element):

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(...);
...
var container = document.createElement("div")
var svg = createAndDrawSVGElement(...); //this returns an svg element
container.appendChild(svg);

var controls = map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM];
var position = controls.length;

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(controls, "insert_at", function(i) {
    if (i === position) {
        var bbox = svg.getBBox();
        ... //etc
    }
}

controls.insertAt(pos, container);
```